# On Click Events of Data Markers in SyncFusion SFChart in iOS in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion's sfChart.ios library for Xamarin in order to display charts in our ios app.

[image]

*Note: Image came from syncfusion website.

I want to bind a onclick function on the data labels.
For example, if i click on USA, there will be a pop up.

I checked the sfchart.ios documentation and there is only a function in the data point click.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement by setting custom views for data marker labels and it can be done by overriding the delegate method **ViewForDataMarkerLabel**. I have prepared a sample for your reference with the custom view as button on data marker labels, to enable the click event and it can be download from the following location.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/166746/ze/DataPointClick1933966243

Thanks,

Manivannan E.

Comment: Hi @Manivannan, Thanks for your reply, I downloaded the sample app and yes I can tap the data markers, but is there a way to tap on the actual name of each data points? For example, in the sample application, I want to tap on USA, CHINA, JAPAN, AUSTRALIA or FRANCE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be achieved by using the CustomChartBehavior class. We have prepared a sample based on this, and it can be downloaded from the following location.

Please let us know if you need further help.

Regards,

Sivaram G.

Comment: **SampleLink:**  [link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/166803/ze/DataPointClick_(1)-82619547)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the CustomChartBehavior class. We have prepared a sample based on this, and it can be downloaded from the following location.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/166803/ze/DataPointClick_(1)-82619547)

Please let us know if you need further help.

Regards,

Sivaram G.